# Why use UserAgentMiddleware when DefaultHeadersMiddleware exists?

Tags: scrapy

`DefaultHeadersMiddleware` can do all `UserAgentMiddleware` can do? So what's the meaning of `UserAgentMiddleware`?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's just for the reason of simplicity.
User agent is a very common thing to change, so being able to set it through the `USER_AGENT` setting or the spiders `user_agent` attribute can be very helpful at times.

For example, changing the user agent from the command line is as simple as:

```
scrapy <command> -s USER_AGENT=something
```

Doing the same thing where you change the default headers would be much more complicated.